# how do i restore my wiped erased imac OS X

Tags: macos, imac

My iMac was stolen,using the find my iphone app I erased, wiped it. 2 days later I got it back. I'm trying to get it workin again.Was told to take it to a apple dealer to be fixed.The closest one is 200km away. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if this would be so simple, the whole feature would be useless. 
If you have a time machine backup, you could get it back online. The other possibility is to use forensic software to restore the disk like http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php.

As long as you are not using FileFault, there is at least a chance.

Comment: Totally agree. Even taking it to the Apple dealer will most probably tell you the same thing!